# Solving an exponential function with a sum

Tags: exponential-function

I have to solve equations of this kind to $x$:

$3^{2x-1} + 1 = 28 \cdot 3^{x-2}$

I don't get the trick to eliminate the $+1$ in the equation.
Can someone show me how I can solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Let $y=3^{x-2}$ so that $y^2=\frac1{27}3^{2x-1}$ and then solve a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we set
$$y = 3^{x-2} \implies y^2 = 3^{2x-4} = \frac{1}{27}3^{2x-1},$$
We can see that

$$3^{2x-1} + 1 = 28 \cdot 3^{x-2}$$
$$\implies 27y^2 + 1 = 28y$$
$$\implies 27y^2 - 28y + 1 = 0$$
$$\implies (27y-1)(y - 1) = 0$$
$$\implies y = \frac{1}{27} \vee y = 1$$
$$\implies 3^{x-2} = \frac{1}{27} \vee 3^{x-2} = 1$$
$$\implies x = -1 \vee x = 2.$$

Answer (score 4):

You could use substitution.

Let $u=3^{x-2}$, so $u^2=3^{2x-4}$ and $3^{3}u^2=3^{2x-1}$

So now we just need to solve $3^{3}u^2+1=28u$.

And the that would give us $u=\frac{1}{27}$ or $u=1$

$3^{x-2}=\frac{1}{27}\Rightarrow x=-1$

$3^{x-2}=1 \Rightarrow x=2$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

write the equation as:
$$
\frac{3^{2x}}{3}+1=28\frac{3^x}{9}
$$

than use the substitution $y=3^x$